# Error when running chkrookit

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run `chkrookit` command in my Ubuntu WSL distribution, it returns the following:

```
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ... INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
```

Is that going to cause any problems for my machine? I have heard that often happens when you run `chkrootkit`.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/possible-malicious-linux-xor-ddos-installed and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626879/chkrootkit-reports-possible-malicious-linux-xor-ddos-installed-how-do-i-verify

Comment: I'll suggest to upload problematic file to https://www.virustotal.com to have some better statistics. Or scan whole system by Linux-based live antivirus like [Avira](https://download.avira.com/download/rescue-system/avira-rescue-system.iso) or [Sophos](https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000033800?language=en_US).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Desktop or Server or Core?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `chrootkit` can return a false positive when you have an executable file in your `/tmp` folder.

So start to check if this is the case - if yes make sure this is *no longer* the case, and run the check again.

Reference [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/possible-infection-chrootkit-reports-linux-xor-ddos-4175605450/).